# Sending data through a function to a modal in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Does anyone know how to pass data to a modal?.

I am trying to pass data to a modal, which there is a function inside a v-for that collects the url of the video to open it later.

The modal is out of v-for because when there are several videos for example of a season it plays the same video.

```
<div class="item_XBG3T" v-for="(item, index) in data.season[show_season]" :key="index">
  <div class="image_33keh lazyloaded" @click.sync="openWatch">
    <img :src="'/_assets/img/covers/episodes/' + item.backdrop" class="lazyload" :alt="item.name">
    <div class="duration_Ob58r">{{ runtime(item.duration) }}</div>
    <div class="play_2ONZn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 55 55"><circle cx="27.5" cy="27.5" r="26.75" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5"></circle><path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5" d="M20.97 40.81L40.64 27.5 20.97 14.19v26.62z"></path></svg></div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="name_hMDmw" v-if="item.episode_number >= 10"><strong>E{{ item.episode_number }}</strong> {{ item.name }}</h2>
  <h2 class="name_hMDmw" v-else><strong>E0{{ item.episode_number }}</strong> {{ item.name }}</h2>
  <div class="overview_1HUXl">{{ item.overview | truncate(125, '...') }}</div>
  <app-play-episode v-if="watchVisible" :video="item.video" :name="item.name" type="iframe" @close="closeWatch"></app-play-episode>
</div>
```

And this is the method that supposedly sends the data to the modal when you open it:

```
openWatch() {
   this.watchVisible = true;
},

closeWatch() {
  this.watchVisible = false;
},
```

This is the route to obtain the data of the episodes:

```
computed: mapState({
  data: state => state.series.show,
  loading: state => state.series.loading
}),

beforeDestroy() {
  this.$store.commit('CLEAR_SERIES_SHOW_DATA');
},

mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch("GET_SERIES_DETAILS", this.$route.params.id);
},
```

The idea is that it does not show me the same url in all the videos that I want to see.

If anyone knows how to achieve this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or the <script> data please? It is difficult to help without the data you're looping over.

Comment: Okay. I already changed it.

Comment: If each item has a different URL stored in `item.video`, they'll all be different, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Not at all. It's supposed to be like that. It shows me all the episodes with their videos each one in their array but when I call them it only shows me the first video of episode 1. When I switch to season 2 in which I have only 1 video, it shows me its corresponding video. The error is when there is more than one episode.

Comment: I think the error is because the modal is inside v-for if I put it outside of it. How would I call the video of the episode I click on?

Answer (score -1):

In the div that is going to be clicked inside the `v-for` put this:

```
@click="openModal(item.video, item.name)"
```

In the open modal method we call the data that we want to give a value later.

```
<app-play-episode v-if="watchVisible" :video="videoplay" :name="videoname" type="iframe" @close="closeWatch"></app-play-episode>
```

The `<app-play-episode>` put it outside the `v-for` and in the `data()` the following:

```
data() {
  return {
    videoplay: null,
    videoname: null,
    watchVisible: false,
  };
},
```

In the `methods` the following:

```
openWatch(video, name) {
   this.videoplay = video;
   this.videoname = name;
   this.watchVisible = true;
},
```

giving a value to them.

Comment: People take time out of their day to help others on this platform, they don't owe you anything, please keep this in mind before responding in the way you did originally.